# Set header for certain file types using Apache2 mod_headers

Tags: httpd, apache-2.2

I'm trying to use mod_headers to set a header for certain file types. Specifically, I want to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `"*"` for `ttf` files. Is there a rule I can add to my VirtualHost that will do this for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `<Files>` tag to do this ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files)), i.e.:

```
<Files "*.ttf">
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Files>
```

This will restrict the `Header` to only files ending in `.ttf`.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Since this wasn't obvious to me right away, it may help someone else too, make sure to run `a2enmod headers`.

Answer (score 1):

And, an alternate option:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\.ttf$" change_header
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=change_header
```

Comment: Is there any reason this would be preferred to the <Files> method?